# Number of Elements in the Legend of an Altair Chart

Tags: python, altair

I would like to control (ie. increase) the number of entries in the legend of an Altair chart but I can't figure out which property controls this behaviour.

By default, Altair charts list 30 elements in the legend. Any further entries get summarised as one line "...271 entries". Is it possible to display more (eg. 50) or fewer entries in the legend?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.Color('Name:N')
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=300
)
```

[image]

Comment: I have seen that there's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758828/making-a-legend-into-multiple-columns-in-altair) about legend columns, that is answering a similar but different question. `legend=alt.Legend(columns=8)` controls how many columns the entries are divided into but it doesn't change the number of elements displayed. Nevertheless, I feel like the answer is in the `legend` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of legend entries can be adjust by changing the `symbolLimit` property.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.Color('Name:N', legend=alt.Legend(symbolLimit=10))
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=300
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Eitan! This is the property I had been looking for. 

As a general remark (not directed at you): Don't know if it's me or if "symbolLimit" is an unfortunate name. It limits the number of entries; "entryLimit" would have been less surprising for me.